# why does this definition of multi qubit Clifford Tableaus not pass symplectic test?

Tags: simulation, clifford-group

I am attempting to write a [module](https://github.com/liorella-qm/CliffordTableau) for composition of Clifford Tableaus using only elementary arithmetic and logical operations. Everything seems to be working fine, except that as far as I understand, the matrices whose columns are the image of each Pauli X/Z operator should be symplectic, namely, pass the test:

$$
g^T\Lambda g = \Lambda
$$
where
$$
\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}0 & I_n \\ I_n & 0\end{pmatrix},
$$
and the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$, namely, I perform all additions and multiplications mod 2.

While single qubit Cliffords do pass this test, e.g, S gate has the tableau:

```
   |x0 z0
--+------
x0|1  0
z0|1  1
s |0  0
```

where `s` is a sign bit,
which is symplectic. However, when I define the S gate on qubit 1 for a 2 qubit circuit in the following way:

```
   |x0 z0 x1 z1
--+------------
x0|1  0  0  0
z0|1  1  0  0
x1|0  0  1  0
z1|0  0  0  1
s |0  0  0  0
```

it is not symplectic using the test defined above! In all other respects, this gate behaves as expected (e.g when composing it with other gates, the composition gives the expected Clifford, as can be seen in the test file [here](https://github.com/liorella-qm/CliffordTableau/blob/master/test_simple_tableau.py).)

So what am I missing here? Which one of my definitions is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ordering the rows/cols as `x0, x1, z0, z1` instead of `x0, z0, x1, z1`.

Comment: thanks! checking with pen and pencil - seems to work. The strange thing is that CNOT for example works with both ordering conventions. I wonder why.

Comment: @Lior you can get "hard" test cases to check your math using `stim.Tableau.random`. CNOT is too well behaved to be a strong test case. Self-inverse, not universal for the Clifford group, and to top it off... *classical*.

Comment: how do I seed the generator? Thanks!

Comment: @Lior there's no supported way to seed `stim.Tableau.random`. But you can save the specific tableaus (use repr or pickling).

Comment: That was a very helpful tip! I caught two serious bugs like this.

Answer (score 0):

following @Craig's answer, I went through the calculation of why the symplectic condition is defined as it is. Perhaps writing out explicitly can help someone out in the future so I'm putting it here.

The basic idea is that two Paulis $P_1$ and $P_2$ can either commute or anti-commute. We can write this out explicitly as:
$$
P_1P_2 = (-1)^xP_2P_1,\,x=0,1
$$
if we connect the Pauli operator to the $\mathbb{F}_2^{2n}$ vector associated with it as @Craig suggested:
$$
P(v)=X_0^{v_0}X_1^{v_1}\cdots Z_n^{v_n}\cdots Z_{2n-1}^{v_{2n-1}}
$$
then the condition
$$
P(v)P(u)=(-1)^xP(u)P(v)
$$
implies that
$$
x=v^T\Lambda u
$$
where
$$
\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}0 & I_n \\ I_n & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The cool thing is that if we now enforce this conditions on the columns of the tableau matrix $g$:
$$
g^T\Lambda g=C
$$
where $C$ is 1 whenever the columns anti-commute and 0 whenever they commute, we find that the condition is $C=\Lambda$. This means that we have the symplectic group structure on these matrices.

Now, when we understand this, it's easy to see that with my original definition of the tableaus, the correct $\Lambda$ is the one that has
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
on the diagonal, namely
$$
\Lambda=\text{diag}(\underbrace{X,..,X}_{\text{n times}}).
$$

Comment: Just a short comment: The $\Lambda$ matrix is the representation of the symplectic form in the chosen basis (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Coordinate_representation) - hence the matrix you use has to be consistent with your basis choice. In your case, the two bases are related by a permutation, thus you get the correct matrix by permuting rows and columns.